# Is there way to count the number of items in a row based on a criteria in one column?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

So I am trying to figure out the formula for this. I've been trying to use `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` functions but to no avail. I'm trying to count the number of occurrences for 30 minutes. It should show 1.

```
=COUNTIF(D7:D17,R7,E7:N10,"")
```

...where D7:D17 is the range in the first column and R7 is "30 minutes". E7:N10 is that range from 1-10 column. I get the error:

> "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size." Then I tried E10:N10 and still got the same error.)

[image: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(A2:A="30 minutes", 
 MMULT(IF(B2:K<>"", 1, 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:K))^0), )))
```

[image: 0]